# Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.34 database server

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, server, mariadb

Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.34 database server. Not working mysql service.
***Mysql MariaDB not working*** and start, restart.  How can I can I get mariadb started
All versions of the latest versions are on Debian.
Below you can see everything in detail.

**This is systemctl status mariadb.service**

```html
debian@replay:~$ systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.34 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─nofile.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-03-27 19:19:31 BST; 7min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 20397 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20398 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20400 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-
  Process: 20491 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 20491 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Mar 27 19:19:30 test systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.34 database server...
Mar 27 19:19:30 test mysqld[20491]: 2022-03-27 19:19:30 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.34-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 20491 ...
Mar 27 19:19:31 test systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 27 19:19:31 test systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 27 19:19:31 test systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.34 database server.
```

**This is journalctl -xe**

```html
-- The job identifier is 1352095.
Mar 27 19:19:29 replayyy sshd[20377]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=106.243.3.194  user=root
Mar 27 19:19:30 replayyy sudo[20390]:   debian : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/debian ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service mysql restart
Mar 27 19:19:30 replayyy sudo[20390]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by debian(uid=0)
Mar 27 19:19:30 replayyy systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.34 database server...
-- Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit mariadb.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 1352198.
Mar 27 19:19:30 replayyy mysqld[20491]: 2022-03-27 19:19:30 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.34-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 20491 ...
Mar 27 19:19:31 replayyy systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mariadb.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 27 19:19:31 replayyy systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The unit mariadb.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 27 19:19:31 replayyy systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.34 database server.
-- Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 1352198 and the job result is failed.
Mar 27 19:19:31 replayyy sudo[20390]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 27 19:19:31 replayyy sshd[20377]: Failed password for root from 106.243.3.194 port 52730 ssh2
Mar 27 19:19:33 replayyy sshd[20377]: Received disconnect from 106.243.3.194 port 52730:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar 27 19:19:33 replayyy sshd[20377]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 106.243.3.194 port 52730 [preauth]
Mar 27 19:19:51 replayyy sshd[20568]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=42.192.167.246  user=root
Mar 27 19:19:52 replayyy sudo[20574]:   debian : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/debian ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -xe
Mar 27 19:19:52 replayyy sudo[20574]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by debian(uid=0)
```